# Redirect with htaccess and WWW

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I'm using the following code to redirect non www URL's on my website to www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

This works fine except for the homepage. If a user goes to the URL website.com, it still brings them website.com until they click on a link on the site and then it readjusts it to www.website.com.

I want it to be like Facebook where if I search in my URL bar Facebook.com, it switches to www.facebook.com before loading the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using regex `.*` which would mean 0 or more length input so it should work.

But you can use this more accurate rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Also make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: This is the same as before. I tried different browsers and clearing my cache as well.

Comment: Open your home page in Firebug and see how many redirections take place.

Comment: It shows 0 (just 200 OK). Interestingly enough, if I go to any other page, example.com/ex or what not, it works and becomes www.example.com/ex, it's only for example.com.

Comment: Ok verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely enabled because it works with all the other pages. Just not the root page. It's very strange.

Comment: Did you run the test as I suggested and did you get 500 error?

Comment: Yes, I added fagadgadgadh at the top of my .htaccess file and got a 500 error.

Comment: Ok what happens when you enter `http://domain.com/fagadgadgadh` does it change to `www`

Comment: Interestingly if I do domain.com/dgadhadh, it goes to www.domain.com/dgadhadh but if I do http:// domain.com/dgadhadh, it goes to www.domain.com/

Comment: That means there are some other redirections happening it either inside code OR inside Apache config.

Comment: I'm really not sure what it could be.

Comment: Only you can investigate this since it is difficult to guess from outside.